# How to cleanly verify if the user input is an integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, validation, integer

I have a piece of code where I ask the user to input a number as an answer to my question.
I can do `to_i` but tricky/garbage inputs would escape through `to_i`. For example, if a user inputs `693iirum5` as an answer then #to_i would strip it to `693`.

Please suggest a function, not a regular expression.
Thanks in advance for replying.

Comment: def check_input(input) input =~ /^\d+$/ end  OK, seriously, why don’t you want a regexp?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will do to validate the input:

```
Integer(gets) rescue nil
```

Comment: how? can you explain what rescue nil means please

Answer (score 7):

In answer to [camdixon's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900490/how-to-cleanly-verify-if-the-user-input-is-an-integer-in-ruby/14900559#comment32265574_14900559) question, I submit this proposed solution.

Use the accepted answer, but instead of `rescue nil`, use `rescue false` and wrap your code in a simple if.

#### Example

```
print "Integer please: " 
user_num=Integer(gets) rescue false 
if user_num 
    # code 
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `input_string.to_i.to_s == input_string` to verify whether the `input_string` is an integer or not without regex.

```
> input_string = "11a12"
> input_string.to_i.to_s == input_string
=> false
> input_string = "11"
> input_string.to_i.to_s == input_string
=> true
> input_string = "11.5"
> input_string.to_i.to_s == input_string
=> false
```

Comment: This will work for normal cases, but is less robust in that, when there are extra spaces at the beginning or the end of the string, it will not work.

Comment: I tried this one, but if user happens to enter spaces, then it does not works.Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

### Use Kernel#Integer

The [Kernel#Integer](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) method will raise `ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer()` if passed an invalid value. The method description says, in part:

> [S]trings should be strictly conformed to numeric representation. This behavior is different from that of String#to_i.

In other words, while [String#to_i](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_i) will *forcibly* cast the value as an integer, Kernel#Integer will instead ensure that the value is already well-formed before casting it.

### Examples Simulating Behavior of `Integer(gets)`

```
Integer(1)
# => 1

Integer('2')
# => 2

Integer("1foo2\n")
# => ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "1foo2\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

to_i is fine but all depends on what You want in case of garbage input. Nil ? the you could use integer(value) and rescue if it's not a integer, the same with Float
If you want 693iirum5 to return something else you could parse the string entered and you will need a regex to check the string. Since you ask not to give a regex i won't, perhaps you can clearify what you really want it to return.

Comment: Don't understand why you claim `to_i` is fine. The OP clearly gives an example where `to_i` does not work the way OP wants.

Comment: to_i in such a case works fine by me, my point is what he wants to happen in such a case was unclear, since he accepted the answer that returns nil, now it is