# How do I check if user input is an integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, user-input

I am trying to loop until user inputs an integer. When user inputs a letter, the following code should print "Think of a number":

```
print "Think of a number "

while user_input = gets.to_i
  if user_input.is_a? Integer
    puts "your number is #{user_input}"
    break
  else
    print "Think of a number "
  end 
end
```

I succeeded with my code when user inputs an integer. However when user inputs a string, the `to_i` method returns `0`, and does not execute the else statement because it is a number.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235863/test-if-a-string-is-basically-an-integer-in-quotes-using-ruby?

Comment: User input is always a string, never an integer.

Comment: Maybe this from @sawa: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14900559/5239030 helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue with your code is `String#to_i` method is omnivorous.

```
"0".to_i #⇒ 0
"0.1".to_i #⇒ 0
"foo".to_i #⇒ 0
```

That said, `user_input` in your code is *always integer*.

What you probably want is to accept digits only (and maybe a leading minus for negatives.) The only concise way to accept a subset of characters is a regular expression.

```
# chomp to strip out trailing carriage return
user_input = gets.chomp 

if user_input =~ /\A-?\d+\z/
  ...
```

The regular expression above means nothing save for digits with optional leading minus.

---

Or, even better (credits to @Stefan)

```
if gets =~ /\A-?\d+\Z/
```

Comment: Don't always use the positive form for matching. Use `!user_input.match?(/\D/)`.

Comment: This is old-school way. Nowadays, you can use `Integer` method.

Comment: @sawa yes, `Integer(exception: false)` but Ruby 2.6 is not yet everywhere. Also, `/\D/` would hardly allow negatives.

Comment: There's also `\Z` (uppercase) which allows you to omit `chomp`.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to accept postive digits, you can use a [range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html):

```
user_input = gets.chomp 
if ('0'..'9').cover? user_input
```

Answer (score 0):

let check below one used `Integer(gets.chomp) rescue ''`

```
print "Think of a number "

while user_input = Integer(gets.chomp) rescue ''
  if user_input.is_a? Integer
    puts "your number is #{user_input}"
    break
  else
    print "Think of a number "
  end
end
```

Comment: `Integer(get.chomp, exception: false)` since Ruby 2.6.

Comment: You can omit `chomp` here, but you probably want to set the base to `10`.

Comment: @Stefan I am not sure what exactly you mean, because by default the  base is 10

Comment: `to_i` has a default base of `10` whereas `Integer()` has a default base of `0`, i.e. it attempts to determine the base from the input: `Integer('0100') #=> 64`

Answer (score -1):

I came across a similar problem. I ended up doing this:

```
if user_input.strip == user_input.to_i.to_s
  # More code here!
end
```

Testing for float would be:

```
if user_input.strip == user_input.to_f.to_s
  # More code here!
end
```

Solved my issue. See if it helps.

Comment: The latter would eliminate integers though.

Comment: Exactly. It checks only for floats. If one needs both, they can be `or`ed.

Comment: Technically `1` is somewhat float since `1 == 1.0 #⇒ true`.

Comment: Also it won’t work on absolutely legit `01` for integers and `1.00` for floats.